# Specify environment version in question&answer

Tags: discussion

Sometimes when I search some question on Stack Overflow, the answer is **not useful** at my local environment framework/system version.

So I think it should be added to the question/answer environment version in question. What do you think about this suggestion?

Comment: Usually, these requirements are often shown in the tags. like "[twitter-bootstrap-3]" having a new SE site just for certain requirements is too specific. As there can be many different enviroments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, sure, to the extent possible, the question and/or answer should be clear about what environments it pertains to, if there may be a difference. Partly that can be done with tags, and the rest can be clarified further within the question [title] itself. I'm reading some implicit things into your question:

1. **Have a formalised system with dropdowns/tags/whatnot to specify environments?**

   The only advantage of formalising this would be searchability. But it's rare that you have multiple questions/answers competing which only differ in the environment; so that searchability would be used very rarely but would be a lot of work to maintain.
2. **Require users to specify their environment?**

   We already have problems getting the minimal viable information for a good question out of people, requiring them to add even more information probably isn't going to make things better and will probably lead to some false information being submitted just to get around any requirements. Also, for many kinds of questions the environment is pretty irrelevant.

So… no. Everyone is free to add environment specific information to their post as necessary already, nothing much that needs to change here. If you do discover something which only pertains to a specific environment but lacks that information, feel free to improve it by suggesting an edit that adds that information, and perhaps an alternative solution for different environments.